# Simple beginner stuff, multiple conditional test

Tags: python, conditional-statements

ok, this seems like it should be really simple but Im a bit confused:

i have two values - domain and ip
its best described with code:

```
        whois_result = Popen(['whois', str(domain)], stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT).communicate()[0]
        debug_output(whois_result)
        if 'Not found' or 'No entries' in whois_result:
                print "Processing whois failure on '%s'" % str(domain)
                print "Trying the IP (%s) instead..." % ip
                whois_result = Popen(['whois', ip], stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT).communicate()[0]
                debug_output(whois_result)
                if 'Not found' or 'No entries' in whois_result:
                        print "complete and utter whois failure, its you isnt it, not me."
                        return False
                else:
                        test = re.search("country.+([A-Z].)",whois_result)
                        countryid = test.group(1)
```

so this function checks the domain whois, if it doesnt find it, its tries a whois with the ip address, but what I want to know is what is the best way to check if the domain is equal to None dont bother with the domain check and go onto the ip check, yet also if the domain is NOT equal to None, do the domain check and then the ip check in that order. Sorry if this is basic, this has me a bit confused. I guess i could set a variable and test for that but is there a more elegant way of doing it ?

if i put at the top a

```
if domain != None:
```

the only way it seems i can do it is by repeating the code or setting a variable, I guess there must be other conditional tests I could use that I dont know about.

EDIT: update 2 based on answers below: - ive also put in the country checking code with my database.

```
def do_whois(data):
        if data is not None: return Popen(['whois', str(data)], stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT).communicate()[0]
        return 'No entries'

def check_whois(data):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        if 'No entries' in data or 'Not found' in data or 'No match for' in data:return False
        id = re.search("country.+([A-Z].)",data)
        if id is None:
                print "we didnt get nuttin from whois"
                return False
        countryid = id.group(1) 
        # fetch country from countrycode db
        cursor.execute("SELECT country,countrycode FROM countries WHERE countrycode = ?",(countryid,))
        country = cursor.fetchone()
        country = country[0]
        print "Server is from: " + country
        return (country,countryid)       

def find_country(domain, ip):
        return check_whois(do_whois(domain)) or check_whois(do_whois(ip))
```

part of the problem with making this robust is the varying values returned by the whois server eg for this IP: 67.222.137.216

the whois server returns :

```
@ : whois 67.222.137.216
#
# Query terms are ambiguous.  The query is assumed to be:
#     "n 67.222.137.216"
#
# Use "?" to get help.
#

#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=67.222.137.216?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2
#

BLUESQUAREDATAVPSLLC BLUESQUAREDATAVPSLLCNET (NET-67-222-137-213-1) 67.222.137.213 - 67.222.137.244
DFW Datacenter DFW-DATACENTER (NET-67-222-128-0-1) 67.222.128.0 - 67.222.159.255


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: When comparing to `None`, it's customary to use `is` or `is not` instead of `==` or `!=`. That's because there is only a single `None` value so it's better to test identity than equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def do_whois(data):
    if data: return Popen(['whois', str(data)], stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT).communicate()[0]
    return 'No entries'

def check_whois(data):
    if 'No entries' in data or 'Not found' in data:return False
    test = re.search("country.+([A-Z].)",whois_result)
    return test.group(1)

def find_whois(domain, ip):
    return check_whois(do_whois(domain)) or check_whois(do_whois(ip))
```

Comment: wow, ok thats a new way of looking at it, so if the function returns False from find_whois it defaults to the check_whois ? thankyou!

Comment: hows that above ? i changed a couple of things. eg whois_result should be data in check_whois and i think in do_whois - the if should be different. not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work :

```
if 'Not found' or 'No entries' in whois_result:
```

This is interpreted as `if ('Not found') or ('No entries' in whois_result)` which always returns True.

To answer your question:

```
if domain != None && domain != 1:
```

-edit-

If you meant `None` instead of "one", you should simply put your IP checking code (which is to be executed after the domain check) on the same indenting level as the domain check.

Comment: thanks guys, ah i see - yeah i kind of guessed that bit hoping it would work and as it didnt choke i assumed it was worky. oh yes, it becomes a bit clearer now. thankyou.

Comment: oh this is a really stupid question, i think ive been staring at this for too long :) awfully sorry. but thanks for clearing up the or statement for me.

Comment: @cigar Get away from the computer, get some fresh air, take a walk or maybe even put it aside until tomorrow. Then when you come back to the code, you might find the answer being a "doh" moment. :)

Comment: always the way :) - same when i play guitar and i cant get it - go away for a day, come back and it seems really easy :) thing is though, im addicted to this thing now, i have to finish it!

Answer (score 0):

This condition is wrong:

```
if 'Not found' or 'No entries' in whois_result:
```

It will always evaluate as "true", because the expression `'Not found' or 'No entries' in whois_result` will always return `'Not found'`.

You need to changed the if-statement to:

```
if 'Not found' in whois_result or 'No entries' in whois_result:
```

Comment: @cigar Heh, such things happen! :) Removed that part of my answer.